# SQL Server : if to Case conversion

Tags: sql-server

Can this `IF` statement be converted to a `CASE` statement? If so, how?  If not, why not? Is it a limitation in SQL Server itself that a `CASE` statement can only return 1 value?

Thanks

```
IF @CategoryName = 'A'
    Begin
        Set @period1 = 'AA18' 
        Set @period2 = '1493'
    End
Else If @CategoryName = 'B'
    Begin
        Set @period1 = 'AA22' 
        Set @period2 = '1563'
    End
Else If @CategoryName = 'C'
    Begin
        Set @period1 = 'AB56' 
        Set @period2 = '2658'
    End
Else
    Begin
        Set @period1 = 'BA03' 
        Set @period2 = '3552'
    End
```

Comment: *"Can this If statement be converted to a Case statement?"* No, as T-SQL has no support for `Case` (`Switch`) statements, only `CASE` expressions, which return a **scalar** value. You could, however, use 2 `CASE` expressions and a `SELECT`.

Comment: T-SQL has no `CASE` statements, only `CASE` expressions, and yes, expressions can only have one value, since there are no tuple types as such. Of course there *are* table types to fill that role, and something like this could be proficiently solved with one: `SELECT @Period1 = Period1, @Period2 = Period2 FROM (VALUES ('A', 'AA18', '1493'), ('B', 'AA22', '1563'), ...) CategoryPeriods(CategoryName, Period1, Period2) WHERE CategoryName = @CategoryName`.

Comment: Put those sets into a a table (or view or function) so you can change the "translation" without having to change code.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment, SQL Server does *not* support `Case` (`Switch`) statements, only `CASE` expressions. These are not the same as `Switch` statements (which are a logical flow operation) and as their name suggests they are an expression. As a result of being an expression then they return a scalar value, like any other expression.

As such, you could convert to above to `CASE` expressions, however, you would need 2; one for each variable. This would look like this:

```sql
SELECT @period1 = CASE @CategoryName WHEN 'A' THEN 'AA18'
                                     WHEN 'B' THEN 'AA22'
                                     WHEN 'C' THEN 'AB56'
                                     ELSE 'BA03'
                  END,
       @period2 = CASE @CategoryName WHEN 'A' THEN '1493'
                                     WHEN 'B' THEN '1563'
                                     WHEN 'C' THEN '2658'
                                     ELSE '3552'
                  END;
```

Comment: Thank you both Larnu and Jeroen.  You have confirmed my suspicion that a Case statement can only return a single value.  I've decided to to keep the If Else If statement for readability reasons

Comment: *"You have confirmed my suspicion that a Case statement can only return a single value."* neither of us have said that, @Robw ... No your suspicions weren't correct.

Comment: @Robw: one more time - `CASE` in T-SQL is ***NOT*** a statement - it's a ***expression*** and that is **fundamentally different** ....

Answer (score 0):

**You can do this without repeating any of the conditions, by using a `VALUES` clause, and left-joining to a unioned `SELECT`.**

The `VALUES` is only needed for the `ELSE`, otherwise you can select straight from the second part.

```sql
SELECT
    @period1 = ISNULL(v2.Period1, v1.Period1)
    @period2 = ISNULL(v2.Period2, v1.Period2)
FROM (VALUES ('BA03', '3552') v1(Period1, Period2)
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT 'AA18', '1493'
    WHERE @CategoryName = 'A'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'AA18', '1493'
    WHERE @CategoryName = 'B'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'AA18', '1493'
    WHERE @CategoryName = 'C'
) v2(Period1, Period2)
```